# How to run a powershell script on all agents under single agent pool

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have setup Release definition with Visual Studio Test Version 2.

I have created an Agent phase and then created visual studio test v2 task for parallel execution of test runs.

**Question:** I want to run a power shell script on all Build Agents(Ten Machines) in Agent pool before execution of VISUAL STUDIO TEST V2 TASK in the same Agent phase. Is there any way to do this or an alternative workaround?

Answer (score 1):

To me, the only way you could do this would be to create an agent phase for each agents you need to run your script on and set the demands with Agent.Name equals yourAgentName.
That would allow you to make sure all agents are targeted.

Comment: You need to create ten to 50 agent phases for 10 to 50 agents? this is what you means?

Comment: That's how I see it. There might be a simpler way to do so.

Comment: I need the simple way out. That's what I am looking for ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deployment groups?

I generally need to run some installation scripts on my agent machines time and again and I've realised the best way to go about this is via a deployment group. When you configure the machine against an agent pool, also setup a deployment agent against a custom deployment pool. The same machine thus has an agent and a deployment agent process running.

Once all machines are listed in the deployment pool all I need to do is create a new release with a deployment group phase, add the script and run the release. The script is then executed on all the participant machines.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts

Comment: How do you target a deployment group/pool in a deployment pipeline YML? It only has a `pool: ` section which targets *agent* pools.

Answer (score 0):

**If you only want to run PowerShell task before VS Test task for each agent machine separately**, you can add the two tasks in **same agent phase**, and set the agent phase as:

[image]

Then the tasks execute order as:

```
agent 1 - PowerShell task
agent 1 - VS Test task
agent 2 - PowerShell task
agent 2 - VS Test task
...
agent 10 - PowerShell task
agent 10 - VS Test task
```

**If you want to execute the PowerShell task on each agent machine firstly and then execute VS Test task on each agent machine**, you should add the two tasks in **two agent phases**, and set both agent phases as:

[image]

Then the task execute order as:

```
agent 1 - PowerShell task
agent 2 - PowerShell task
...
agent 10 - PowerShell task
agent 1 - VS Test task
agent 2 - VS Test task
...
agent 10 - VS Test task
```

Comment: If we are using Multi-Agent Option for a phase , then why there is need to do for each agent? Like , VsTest V2 will execute on all agents in single phase if you selected above options. If i add powershell script before VsTest Task then it should also execute on all agents in single go like VsTest task is doing. What do you think?

Comment: @DevOps The main difference of using one agent phase or two agent phases is the executing order. If the two tasks in same agent phase, it execute the two tasks for each agent phase. If using two agent phases for each task, it executing Powershell task for 10 times, then execute VS Test task for 10 times.

Comment: And when i execute the script of PowerShell which connects with SQL installed on that Build Agent , it throwing this error: Error:
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishin
g a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Loc
ating Server/Instance Specified)"
Retry in 10 seconds.  Attempts left: 5
Error:

Comment: @DevOps The error message is mainly depend on the script you write, it's a different question with this question.

Comment: @DevOps If this question has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And for the error to connect your SQL server, you can create a new question, with your script and the detail logs there. And it will also help other members who search related questions.

Comment: @DevOps Did you run the tasks on the tem agent machines successful now?